# mysql data not displaying in table format

Tags: html

I want to display mysql database data in table format using php. my code is not working. I have data in table and connection is also made. However only the column title gets displayed, and not the database data.

```
<html>  
<body> 
<table style="width:300px"> 
<tr> <td>Empno</td> <td>Ename</td> <td>address</td> <td>City</td> </tr> 

<?php include("conn.php"); 
$res=mysql_query("select * from info"); 
$res=mysql_query($res); 
$i=1; 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) { ?> 
<tr> <td><?php echo ($row['empno']);?></td> 
<td><?php echo ($row['ename']);?></td> 
<td><?php echo ($row['address']);?></td> 
<td><?php echo ($row['city']);?></td> </tr> 
<?php $i++; } ?> </table> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: HTML CODE <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>table format</title>
<style>
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
<td>Empno</td>
<td>Ename</td>
<td>address</td>
<td>City</td>
</tr>

Comment: Might want to share some code, no one is going to guess what you have or need.

Comment: PHP CODE <?php
include("conn.php");
$res=mysql_query("select * from info");
$res=mysql_query($res);
$i=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
 ?>
    <tr>
  <td><?php echo ($row['empno']);?></td>
  <td><?php echo ($row['ename']);?></td>
  <td><?php echo ($row['address']);?></td>
  <td><?php echo ($row['city']);?></td>
  </tr>
    <?php $i++;
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @daniel edit your question add your code there for god sake

Comment: @rick i have shared the code in comment area

Comment: @rick i tried to post the code in the main area where u posted, however it was not allowing me to do so

Comment: Edited, don't put code in the comments you can see how difficult it is to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code you are executing two time query :

```
$res=mysql_query("select * from info"); 
$res=mysql_query($res); // <------ Remove this code
```

Also what is your file name extension ? It should be `.php` as you have tag html in your question. If it is in `.html` change it to `.php`

On side note don't use **mysql_*** function since it deprecated see more [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: @daniel execute `select * from info` query on your phpmyadmin and check it gives you the result or not?

Comment: Thanks Rak, I changed the file extension as .php from html and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a bit more info about your problem please - maybe a snippet of your PHP code?

For example, are you using mysqli or PDO?

Your rowset from the database should be returned as an array - try a **print_r($rowset)** and see what you get back.

Also check that there's actually data in there - if you've used a third party application (like Toad for MySQL or MySQL Workbench for example), make sure you've committed the data (if auto-commit is turned off).

Edit:
Try this instead

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM info"; 
$res = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: I am using mysql and not mysqli

Comment: data is available in db and i am not using any third party application. where should i insert print_r($rowset)?

Comment: You're preparing your query twice.
This is probably what you wanted to do.

$sql = "SELECT * FROM info"; 
$res = mysql_query($sql);